# Java RestFull Service

Tags: java, java-ee, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

пытаюсь добавить рестфул сервис в свое вебприложение

сам сервис выглядит вот так

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/validate_login")
@Service
public class ValidateUserLoginService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{login}")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
    public boolean validate(@PathParam("login")String login){
       return userService.loginExist(login);
    }
}
```

при запуске приложения я получаю предупреждение такого плана

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/stanislav.alekseev/IdeaProjects/flowershop/target/flowershop/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
```

за все это дело отвечает jersy

вот он в web.xml

```
 <

    servlet>
            <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.accenture.flowershop.rest</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

для этого в pom.xml прописаны зависимости

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-spring4</artifactId>
      <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>
```

получается что при попытке отдать запорос на свой рестфул сервис я получаю в консорли браузера вот такую ошибку

jquery-2.2.4.js:9175 GET http://localhost:8083/rest/validate_login?login=stas 404 (Not Found)

скорей всего изза того что анотации моего рестфул сервиса не распознаются и запрос уходит в никуда

я пробовал менять настройки томката и в файле проперти указал чтобы этот 
jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar не сканировался ,но ошибка осталась

есть у кого то идеи по поводу того,что делать?
сам томкат 8.5 java 12

Comment: Почему вы одновременно используете спринг и JAX-RS(java ee)? Не легче использовать один фреимворк?

Comment: это учебное задание,изначально был спринг,затем добавляли веб сервисы,кстати wsdl отлично работает

Comment: Если ответ решил ваш проблему, нажмите на галочку чтобы принять его + на стрелочку вверх.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать класс `ApplicationConfig`(а строки в `web.xml` удалите).

Он должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("rs")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    private final Set<Class<?>> classes;

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> c = new HashSet<>();
        c.add(Class1.class);//сами классы служб. 
        c.add(Class2.class); //Нужно добавить все классы где есть аннотация Path
        classes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses () {
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Также вы говорите что используете `Jersey`, но в логах у вас почему-то

```
jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar
```

Вы уверены что вы используете Джерси? Если нет, то попробуйте добавить ее через IntelliJ.

Левой кнопкой мыши по имени проекта(на картинке) -> `Add Framework Support` -> Ставите версию Java EE 7(если оставить 8 то IDEA не найдет библиотеку) -> `RESTful WS.` -> `Jersey`(картинка 2).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я сам не понимаю откуда взялась jakarta,но она присутсвует в библиотеке проекта

Comment: Так вы сделали то что я написал?

Comment: из доступных у меня поддержка только  groovy

Comment: идея community edition

Comment: А другие шаги вы выполнили? Да, в community нельзя добавлять фреимворки связанные с JEE, только через maven

Comment: сделал ничего не работает как и прежде,проблема в том ,что скорей всего изза того что где то конфликтуют версии библиотек,анотации рестфул сервиса -не работают,тоесть запрос уходит ,но до рестфул сервиса он не доходит